# Stop cloudflare injecting HTML into my code

Tags: javascript, html, cloud, cloudflare

I have a few pieces of example JS and HTML that are stored in .js and .html files on my server. My server is run using cloudflare as a DNS server (I'm hosting it on my own server).

I read this code to display using code-prettify in my code, and it works in my local machine. When I push this code to my server, there are a few extra elements and additions to elements in my html.

This is the html file, and how it shows in the browser on my localhost

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="../../libraries/p5.min.js"</script>
<script src="../../libraries/p5.graphing.js"></script>
<script src="xySample.js"</script>
</html>
```

This is the html that displays when my server is through cloudflare

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="../../libraries/p5.min.js" type="5679b6186495861c611c81b4-text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../libraries/p5.graphing.js" type="5679b6186495861c611c81b4-text/javascript"></script>
<script src="xySample.js" type="5679b6186495861c611c81b4-text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/a2bd7673/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js" data-cf-settings="5679b6186495861c611c81b4-|49" defer=""></script>
</html>
```

On my cloudflare dashboard, I've been to the Page Rules tab and have passed in the url of both the HTML which my code should show up in as well as the location of the HTML thats being injected and disabled rocket loader for both. This didnt work, even after clearing cookies.

How do I stop this HTML injection by cloudflare. Thanks!

Comment: So, these files are not your *website*, per se, they are data files that you will load and display, for example, in a syntax-highlighted code view? If so, you need to convince cloudflare of this fact. You might be able to do it by simply changing the actual file extension on the server from .js or .html to .txt. Or, If they keep injecting stuff into your code, change it so it looks like raw data: base64 and/or zip the whole file before saving it on the server, and then decode it after you fetch it in your web page via Ajax request. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just disable **Rocket Loader** in your *Cloudflare dashboard*